# Oracle Apex - selecting date with different hours

Tags: sql, oracle, time, oracle19c

We have a web application which we store a date from the user. The date is stored on an Oracle 19c database as a `date` field.

The problem we have is that when we select the date it's coming with different hours, like it's taking into account the timezone or something. So, for example one person can see the date *2021-05-20T13:00:00Z* while another somewhere else can see *2021-05-20T12:00:00Z*.

Is there a way to prevent this behavior, and have everybody get the same date and time?

**Update**
Most likely the problem resides in Oracle Apex, not Oracle database!
We use a very old version of Apex, 1.x it seems so maybe this problem doesn't happen on newer versions.

Comment: Are there multiple sources/processes that are updating this field? How is it getting updated?  You are going to need to provide at lot more detail, maybe code example.

Comment: If the column (not "field") is really defined as a DATE data type, then it has only date and time, down to the second, and knows nothing about time zones.  To comment further, we would need to see the actual SELECT statement, and DDL for the table.  I will say that DATE and TIMESTAMP (which _can_ include timezone info) are _binary_ structures which can be displayed in several different character formats.

Comment: @EdStevens I know that **date** doesn't have timezone, that's why I'm finding this odd. But think that maybe something else is influencing this. We use APEX here, maybe it's messing with the date?

Comment: To expand a bit on @OldProgrammer (we were writing at the same time) it could be that process A updates the column, but before it is COMMITed, process B reads and so sees the pre-updated value.  Processes cannot see uncommitted changes from other processes.

Comment: @EdStevens this problem doesn't seem related to concurrency. If I access the database using SQLDeveloper and query the date it shows me it correctly. That's why I think it could be Apex messing with it somehow.

Comment: _"That's why I think it could be Apex messing with it somehow."_  which brings us back to debugging invisible code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is often problem when you use, for example, java.util.Timezone,java.sql.Date or java.util.Date type in java instead of oracle.sql.Date

Comment: Apex is Java, and this seems very likely to be the issue, it's like creating a new Date in JavaScript where it automatically sets the time using the browser timezone. I have seen that in our code when doing selects they are converting the date to string, so again, another thing that points to this being the issue!